# How to summon an invisible entity upon spawning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to summon a slime that is invisible when you summon it, but whenever I run the command below, the slime appears for a half a second and then disappears.

```
/summon slime ~ ~1 ~ {NoGravity:1b,Size:0,NoAI:1,Silent:1,DeathLootTable:"empty",ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:100,Duration:999999,ShowParticles:0b}]}
```

There is no Invisible tag for slimes, so I was wondering if there was a way to make the slime completely invisible when you spawn it. I only need the slime to be summoned for about a second before being killed or despawned.

I am on Minecraft 1.14.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-72774

One possible workaround is to summon them out of sight, then teleport them to their destination at least one tick later.

Answer (score 0):

i used this command and it worked fine maybe try this? `/summon minecraft:slime ~ ~1 ~ {Size:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:2147483647}]}`